# Decorate spring boot repository

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot API that's supposed to be deployed later this month. We created our own interface for a repository, and extended the CrudRepository. Spring boot autowires everything.

What I would like to do is add more logging capabilities, such as `LOGGER.info("searched for solution ID")`.

Currently our code looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductSolutionRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductSolution, String> {

    public List<ProductSolution> findBySolutionId(@Param("solutionId") int solutionId);
```

Since Spring configures everything don't really see a way of decorating these functions to add logging functionality. Can someone help me out by pointing me to the documentation, showing a nice example, or explaining the concept behind logging decorators?

Comment: Lombok or AOP perhaps ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258158/how-to-instrument-advice-a-spring-data-jpa-repository, what you need is AOP

Answer (score 4):

First, I would like to point out some redundant codes for you.

- You don't need to annotate the repository with `@Repository`, spring boot can autowire it automatically.
- `@Param` is used when you write a sql with `@Query`, you just need to declare your parameters here.

The repository is the `dao` layer. A normal practice, you should create a `service` for each repository and autowire the repository into the service. Then you can implement transaction or write logs there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single file `AOP Logging Aspect` using `AspectJ` cutting across your repository interfaces layer and logging method name, input args and output.

Assuming for this purpose a `RepositoryLoggingAspect` class, you'd have to annotate it first with `@Aspect`:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class RepositoryLoggingAspect {
//..
}
```

And then create a Pointcut aiming at your repository package you want to cut-accross:

```
@Pointcut("within(package.of.my.repositories..*)")
public void repositoriesPackagePointcut() {}
```

And finally define the logging logic in an `@Around` annotated method:

```
@Around("repositoriesPackagePointcut()")
public Object logMyRepos(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  //log method name using: joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
  //log method arguments using: Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs())
  //store and log method output using: Object myResult = joinPoint.proceed();
}
```