# Set comment for every queries ran by Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

All MongoDB queries done by the Spring app must have a comment, right now this is done by calling the method ***comment*** on ***org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query***.

```
public <T> T findOne(Query query, Class<T> klass) {
    query.comment("my comment");
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, klass);
}
```

That means I have to use the ***MongoTemplate*** object for making all my queries and I'm loosing the abstraction provided by Spring Data (I have to implement the method instead of just declaring it).

Is there a way to configure Spring Data to apply a function (that will set the comment) for every queries ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may achive the required behaviour by means of AOP.
There should be a lot of samples over the internet, for example: [Stack Overflow: How to Instrument Advice a Spring Data JPA Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258158/how-to-instrument-advice-a-spring-data-jpa-repository)

Comment: It doesn't look like this is correct, unless you know a way to access the Query object that is generated through AOP?