# Spring + AspectJ pointcut on CrudRepository and Annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have @Tenantable annotation to decide for pointCut :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface Tenantable {
}
```

this my aspect :

```
 @Slf4j
    @Aspect
    @Configuration
    public class TenancyAspect {

        @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
        public void publicMethod() {}

        @Around("publicMethod() && @within(com.sam.example.aspect.aspectexample.model.Tenantable)")
        public Object tenatable(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("my operations ...");
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }
    }
```

This is working without any problem for this service class :

```
@Tenantable
@Service
public class MyService(){
    public void doSomething(){
            ...
    }
}
```

my aspect is running when I call doSomething() method, It is ok but I want to implement aspect for CrudRepository interface that belongs spring data.

I have changed my Aspect to achieve this like below :

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class TenancyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}


    @Pointcut("this(org.springframework.data.repository.Repository)")
    public void repositoryExec(){}


    @Around("publicMethod() && repositoryExec() && @within(com.sam.example.aspect.aspectexample.model.Tenantable)")
    public Object tenatable(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("my operations ...");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

this is repository :

```
@Tenantable
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository{
}
```

But it doesn't work when I call any method inside of  MyRepository.

Is there anyway to do this?

**Edit :** 
It works for all repositories when I apply these :

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))")
```

and  exclude this :

`@within(com.sam.example.aspect.aspectexample.model.Tenantable)`

But I need this anotation to apply it for  specific repositories.

Comment: How can you expect it to work for `MyService`? The class does not extend or implement anything related to `Reporitory`. or `@CrudRepository`. Or do you want to target another class? If so, please show that class incl. package name.

Comment: It is just sample that I have wanted to show it is working on concrate class which has @tenantable anotation. But it is not working for repositories.

Comment: Exactly! So where is your example for what is _not_ working? This is what you are looking for answers here, are you not? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this is how you get your answeres around here.

Comment: @kriegaex I have edited

Comment: All you did is add the `MyRepository` interface. Where is a class implementing that interface and how is it used? What about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do you not understand? Did you even read the article? I cannot compile and run your code, as it is incomplete. You are hiding exactly those parts of the application which you have problems with. This does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having taken another look, I think I know what is going on here: You are assuming that just because you made your annotation `@Inherited`, it will be inherited by implementing classes if you annotate an interface. But this assumption is wrong. `@Inherited` only works in exactly one case: when extending an annotated base class. It does not work for annotated interfaces, methods etc. This is also documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html):

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

As soon as you annotate your implementing class, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `repositoryExec` pointcut should end with `+` to advice all subclass of `Repository`

```
  @Pointcut("this(org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+)")
```

Comment: like this ` @Pointcut("this(org.springframework.data.repository.Repository.+)")` ??

Comment: I have tried it but it doesnt work for my CrudRepository 's methods.

Comment: can you look my edit? my annotation dont work for Repositories

Comment: You try to advice method on repository but annotation is placed in service?

Comment: is it impossible to specify on interface or I should research and try more ? You know?