# Spring repository : @CacheEvict on save methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa, caching

I'd like to add a `@CacheEvict()` decorator to my save / saveAll methods from my repository.

I've tried to override the methods by using custom implementation by reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036159/spring-data-override-save-method) but I don't want to rewrite the method implementation, just call the default one with more behavior. None of the solutions provided work well for my case, or require far too much customization.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

   // This is working fine as its a custom query method
   @Cacheable(value = "ENTITIES")
   MyEntity findByCategory(String category);

   // This isn't working as it won't implement the function correctly. Save don't work anymore here.
   @CacheEvict(value = "ENTITIES", key = "#entity.hashCode()")
   <S extends MyEntity> S save(S entity);

}
```

I could call the cache eviction manually from the method's body, but I can't just override the `save()` method and call the `super.save()` since I only use interfaces and let Spring generate the implementation.

Any advices?

Comment: I think it should be returning <S extends MyEntity> in the save method. it should be working fine

Comment: Nice try but sorry, that was just a mistake pasting my sample code!

Comment: Is your problem is the "save" isn't working (data is not saving) or the cache is not evicted correctly?

Comment: Don't... Please don't instead use proper 2nd level caching of your persistence provider.

Comment: Why don't you pass and return MyEntity to the save method. And second HashCode is not a good idea for the key and are you sure that findByCategory uses this as key as well? And you have no write transaction anymore. You have to add @Transactional to save.

Comment: Could you apply an AOP based solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258158/how-to-instrument-advice-a-spring-data-jpa-repository

Comment: The real question here is "how do I add such a decorator to the default repository methods?" Don't mind the use of the cache, I know the 2nd level cache, and I know the hashCode isn't the best solution.

Comment: An aspect (AOP)  which interacts with the CacheManager programmatically and uses reflection to determine name of the cache to clear should be a clean solution: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-evict-cache

Comment: there's official example from spring data
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/caching/CachingUserRepository.java
it's exactly the same with what you wrote
so it should be working (the save)
if the cacheevict not working means you specified the wrong key

Comment: @NaFelixWimpyWijaya Yes I feel like this solution should be working, but I can't manage how. The save method doesn't rise any exception but still, don't save anything as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found. It was dummy.
Just removed the @Transactional(readOnly = true). It was preventing the save from working.

So just overriding the signature of the method is enough to add some decorators without caring about the implementation.

```
@Override
@CacheEvict(value = "ENTITIES", key = "#p0.getKeyWhateverItIs()")
<S extends Feature> S save(S entity);
```

And yes, the key value was wrong as well, but not implicated in the non-working `save` method.